# Sorting Facebook Friend Based on Degree of Friendship

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application which sorts people on my app, based on degree of friendship. However, after latest release of Facebook API, the number of friends comes in a list of 20 while checking in GRAPH API. Earlier all the list can be retrieved in one go

My application searches and show wrong results.

1- Number of mutual friends are incorrect
2- My first degree friends are shown in other friend list (2nd degree & beyond list)

Can someone help me on this

Comment: please add the relevant code, this is quite broad right now

Comment: $db_users = "USERS from DATABASE";
$friends_use_app = $this -> facebook -> api("/me/friends?fields=installed&limit=5000");//My Friends who is using APP.


I want to differentiate MY FB FRIENDS and  OTHER USERS and showing in two tabs. Basically, i'm fetching $db_users then extract users who is my friend as well as used app and show in MY FB FRIENDS tab, While other users who is not my friends then it's showing in OTHER USERs tab.

Comment: This solution is works fine before but after NEW FB API (Facebook SDK 4.*+), I have found that FB added LIMIT in friends API, While in OLD API we can retrieve all Friends list at once. But now it doesn't work. So i have tried API with giving LIMIT parameters, But it's not works either, Some of my friends who is using APP is not displaying in $friends_use_app.

So I'm confused here whether i'm doing anything wrong or what!!! :(

Comment: please edit your question, and don´t add relevant info in comments only

Comment: btw, you can´t get access to all friends anymore. that´s just how it is now.

Comment: Let me make it more clear, So I have 10 people registered on my app. Now out of those 10 people on my app, based on defined criteria, I want to show my facebook friends & other friends in separate tabs. I am not trying to extract complete friendlist since I believe it is not available with new FB API.

Comment: then why not just use /me/friends? you get all friends who authorized your app too. other friends are easy too, you can just store all users in your database.

Comment: Earlier while fetching Facebook friends, I was able to fetch it in one go, however now FB has added limit of I believe 20. I want exactly how candy crush is able to show your first degree friendlist

Comment: use paging. it´s all explained in the official docs. setting the limit to 5000 is a very bad idea, that´s a very buggy solution.